# How do I update an Elm package?

Tags: elm

I have a dependency in `elm.json` to `elm/browser` version 1.0.1. How do I update it using `elm`?

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "direct": {
            "elm/browser": "1.0.1",
            ...
```

Simply updating it by hand in `elm.json` makes Elm complain:

```
-- INVALID PACKAGE DEPENDENCIES --------------------------------------- elm.json

The dependencies in your elm.json are not compatible.
```

Answer (score 7):

If you have access to install npm packages on your system, then I recommend the `elm-json` package:

https://github.com/zwilias/elm-json

It was designed to "Install, upgrade and uninstall Elm dependencies", and it's easy to use!

If you don't have the ability to install npm packages, then I would remove the `elm/browser` line from `elm.json` and install again with `elm install elm/browser`.

Comment: `elm-json` can also be installed without npm - just download the executable at releases in the github repository.

Comment: From the README: `NOTE: This is very much a work in progress. May mess up your files completely. Use with care.`